# Video from vhs via USB capture device on Linux

Tags: linux, video, video-capture

I want to transfer video from a VHS tape to my computer with Arch Linux, using a USB capture device that comes with [Roxio Easy VHS to DVD](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/easy-vhs-to-dvd/standard/overview.html), which I recently bought. I tried to plug in the device, and it was properly recognized. From `/var/log/messages.log`,

```
em28xx #0: Identified as Pinnacle Dazzle DVC 90/100/101/107 / Kaiser Baas Video to DVD maker / Kworld DVD Maker 2 (card=9)
saa7115 3-0025: saa7113 found (1f7113d0e100000) @ 0x4a (em28xx #0)
em28xx #0: Config register raw data: 0x50
em28xx #0: AC97 vendor ID = 0xffffffff
em28xx #0: AC97 features = 0x6a90
em28xx #0: Empia 202 AC97 audio processor detected
em28xx #0: v4l2 driver version 0.1.2
em28xx #0: V4L2 video device registered as video1
em28xx #0: V4L2 VBI device registered as vbi0
```

Is there any software that enables me to capture video coming from this device? I don't mind if it is console or GUI based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as a standard V4L2 device, which means that you can record with VLC, mplayer, etc. etc. etc...

Comment: Any clue on how to do that with, say, VLC?

Comment: `Media` | `Convert/Save...` | `Capture Device` | `Video for Linux 2` and I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: OK, I'll try that. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you come across this page after 2019, there is a slight change for the VLC info from Ignazio.  I was just given a Roxio Creator USB by my sister - brand new, still in the box from over 10 years ago.  Here's what you need now.

- Be sure the key is NOT plugged in
- Open a terminal, and enter the command:  ls /dev/video*
  (you may see, for example, /dev/video0 and /dev/video1)
- Plug in the key, and re-enter the command:  ls /dev/video*
- You will now see a new device.  In my case it was /dev/video2
- In VLC, use:  Media -> Convert/Save -> Capture Device -> /dev/video2

With that small change, it is possible to select the video settings (mine show NTSC, PAL, etc etc) and get started.